# tlmgr command line and GUI

Tags: texlive

I'm using on terminal `tlmgr --gui` to open the GUI. No problem.

But I'd like to open the GUI with the *default repository* loaded and the *update* option selected.

[Online documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#option) shows

> `tlmgr --gui update`
>
> starts you directly at the update screen. If no action is given, the
>   GUI will be started at the main screen.

but I got the message

```
tlmgr update: specify --list, --all, --self, or a list of package names.
```

Also I tried `tlmgr --gui update --list` and the output was

```
tlmgr: package repository http://www.las.ic.unicamp.br/pub/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2014/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: no updates available
```

So how to open the GUI and repository loaded and showing the updates available?

Comment: I get the same message, apart from a different repository of course, but I've have already updated manually this afternoon. Do you have some automatic - update?

Comment: My impression is that it's an error in the documentation. The `--gui` option seems to be ignored.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I also tried the command after I had updated. So this is the reason for the last warning. But I would like to open the GUI ready to update.

Answer (score 3):

This is left-over in the documentation from the version 1 of the gui, when there were different tabs.

Now the gui cannot be combined with other actions.

Comment: So you are saying that I can not open the GUI and load the default repository automatically?

Comment: Yes, that is the current status